# Use PK instead of object references in many-to-many associations with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, json.net

I'm using EF6 and SQLite to cache API responses. So I have data models which are used both as models for Json.NET and as entities models for EF6. On 1:1 and 1:n associations all works fine, but I have problem on n:m associations, because EF6 identifies these associations using object references instead of primary keys of objects.

I created simple example for better derscribing of my problem:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("courses")]
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

JSON API response with list of students:

```
{[
   { 
     "id": 1
     "name": "Paul",
     "courses": [
       { 
         "id": 1
         "name": "Course A"
       },
       { 
         "id": 2
         "name": "Course B"
       }
     ]
   },
   { 
     "id": 2
     "name": "John",
     "courses": [
       { 
         "id": 1
         "name": "Course A"
       }
     ]
   }
]}
```

So after deserializing, Course A in Paul's list is different instance from Course A instance in John's list. But logically these objects are same.

After I add these Students into DbContext.DbSet it fails, because EF6 is trying to add a "Course A" entity into the Courses table twice with same primary key. After I manually changed reference of Course A in John's collection to point to the Paul's Course A, it worked fine - entries are created in the StudentCourses join table.

So, my questions are:

1) Is there any way to set Json.NET to use same instance for value-equal objects (after overriding Equals and ==)?

2) Is there any way to force EF6 to use PK properties as identifiers of relationships?

3) Is there any better pattern to handle my problem?

//EDIT
I created code/response only to illustrate core of my problem, but in reality I'm using much more complex responses and a lot of endpoints... so I need universal solution - I think that the best way is to handle it during deserialization - if object of same type with identical id was already created during deserialization, use reference to it instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSON but the DataContractSerializer has an option to preserve reference. Maybe this is the same thing http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm

Comment: @user2697817 I know, but this option works only on special JSON responses with $id and $ref fields, but I need to "pair" two JSON objects using contained value

Comment: I think GraphDiff could be something for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you could try something like this to take the disconnected poco version of your entity and replace it inline with the connected version. This example is just mapped to your example but you could do this recursively for your more complex design.

```
void Main()
{
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(yourJson);

    json.ForEach(x => {
        var student = GetEntity<Student>(s => s.Id == x.Id);

        if(student != null)
        {
            //replace disconnected entity with connected reference
            x = student;

            student.Courses.ForEach(sc =>
            {
                var course = GetEntity<Course>(c => c.Id == sc.Id);
                sc = course;
            });
        }
    });
}

public T GetEntity<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
{
    return yourContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```